# Github API to download a zipball/tarball which includes LFS files

Tags: github-api, git-lfs

I am retrieving a tarball from Github using the v3 API, i.e. `https://api.github.com/repos/my-account/my-project/tarball/my-ref`.

However, this project uses Git-LFS for some files, and the resulting archive doesn't contain the files but the LFS link:

```
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:fc03a2eadf6ac4872de8ad96a865ed05c45c416c5ad40c9efa3c4bcbe5d0dc9e
size 1284
```

What can I do in order to get an archive having the LFS links replaced by the real file content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Git-lfs [API](https://github.com/github/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/api/http-v1-batch.md) shows how and where to make requests.
In your case, assuming you know the `OID` you're looking for (it's stored in the [pointer](https://github.com/github/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/spec.md#the-pointer)) you should:

`POST https://github.com/your-account/your-repo/objects` with something like:

```
{
    "operation": "download",
    "objects": [
      {
       "oid": "fc03a2eadf6ac4872de8ad96a865ed05c45c416c5ad40c9efa3c4bcbe5d0dc9e",
       "size": 1284
      }
    ]
}
```

Maybe you can ommit the `size` part - it's not really specified. Also you can request several `OIDs` together in the [batch request](https://github.com/github/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/api/http-v1-batch.md#successful-responses)

The response will look something like [this](https://github.com/github/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/api/http-v1-batch.md#successful-responses) and will contain download links to the blobs themselves if they exist or some error for each of them (the response as a whole always returns as 200 if you are authenticated).

Comment: So I guess that I have to open the archive, scan all the files for the ones looking like a LFS pointer, and replace them by the downloaded files. Am I doing it right?

Comment: As ugly as it sounds, I think yes because it doesn't seem that they thought about this usecase (or thought of it but didn't implement it yet.)  what is your usecase? maybe it's better for you to `git clone` the repo and then tar it yourself?

Comment: I wanted to avoid installing Git on the build machine(s), but I guess that I will have to install it, plus git-lfs.